# how to shuffle a binary array a specific amount

Tags: python, arrays, random, shuffle

I have a binary array. I want to shuffle it such that *n* percent of random elements stay in the same place and the rest get shuffled. Another way of putting it is, I have a binary array and I want to create a second array that is of same length and *n* percent similar when compared to the first using difflib

I'm using
    `random.shuffle`
to shuffle the array but can't find info on the percent part of my question.

```
import random

array = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
random.shuffle(array)
print(array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using numpy, you can create a boolean mask to pull approximately n-fraction of the arr, shuffle the pulled sample, then put the shuffled result back into the masked locations.

```py
import numpy as np

n = 0.2
arr = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

# create boolean mask of about fraction n
ix = np.random.choice([True, False], size=arr.size, replace=True, p=[n, 1-n])

# pull the masked portion and shuffle
arr_shuff = arr[ix]
np.random.shuffle(arr_shuff)

# reinsert
arr[ix] = arr_shuff

arr
# returns:
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: i get the error `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'shuffle'` when testing this code but `np.random.shuffle` seems to work

Comment: oops.  it is supposed to be `np.random.shuffle`.  fixed now

Comment: This may be a separate question, but if I want to use this code to return several shuffled arrays (all different, but based on the same initial array) how might I do it? When using a for loop I get the same shuffled array several times `for i in range(10):
    print(arr)`

Comment: Wrap up the code into a function that takes an array as an input.  The first line of function would be to create a copy of the array using `arr.copy()`, then perform the operations on the copy so as to not change the original array

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would find a standard function for this.
You can swap n * len(array) with other items in the array:

```
import random

array = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
n = 0.2

for i in range(int(n*len(array))):
    ri = random.randrange(len(array))
    array[i], array[ri] = array[ri], array[i]

print(array)
```

however, if the array is filled with only zero's or one's you will get no diff.